# Subset of values from matrix in R

Tags: r, subset, mean

I'm trying to extract a subset of values from a data frame to get the mean of the subset but I can't figure out how to do it.

I tried this

```
kg_name=cat(shQuote(k_categories[1,]), "\n")
m[1] = mean(subset(dt, dt[2]==kg_name)[,1])
```

So the categories of values that I have to extract are in this k_categories vector. They are for example one, two and three. On the first line of code I add quotes to the values so I can get "one", "two", "three". Now the second line tries to calculate the mean by extracting the values of the two-column data-frame dt that matches the string "one" in the second column.

Now it all works fine if I do this

```
m[1] = mean(subset(dt, dt[2]=="one")[,1])
```

But if I extract the name of the category from k_categories then I get this error (I also put part of the trace)

```
Error in matrix(unlist(value, recursive = FALSE, use.names = FALSE), nrow = nr,  : 
length of 'dimnames' [2] not equal to array extent 
8 matrix(unlist(value, recursive = FALSE, use.names = FALSE), nrow = nr, 
dimnames = list(rn, cn)) 
7 Ops.data.frame(dt[2], kg_name) 
6 eval(expr, envir, enclos) 
5 eval(e, x, parent.frame()) 
4 subset.data.frame(dt, dt[2] == kg_name) 
3 subset(dt, dt[2] == kg_name)
```

Edit (add dt data frame example)

```
         Values     Categories
              1            one
              3            two
              2          three
              4            one
              3            two
              2            two
```

Comment: Can you give an example of the type of matrix you have and the subsets for which you want to calculate summary statistics?

Comment: Done. I did a print of the head of the matrix

Answer (score 0):

This script gives me the mean value.

```
a = c("one", "two", "three", "one", "two", "two")
b = c(1, 3, 2, 4, 3, 2)
d = data.frame(values = b, categories = a)

uniques = unique(a)

for(i in 1:length(uniques))
  print(mean(subset(d, categories==uniques[i])$values))
```

Instead of printing the value, you could save it to a variable.  I guess I'm not really understading what you're trying to do...

Comment: More or less but the problem is that I can't use categories=="one" since I won't normally know the name of the categories so instead of "one" I need to use the value of a vector with the names of the categories but apparently R doesn't like that. That's exactly my problem above.

Comment: Is that second version working for you? I did that exactly and it didn't work.

Comment: Yes, it executes with no problems for me.  I am using R version 3.1.1 (2014-07-10)

Comment: Yeah I use exactly the same but it doesn't work, very strange.